# Systemd: Unknown lvalue '_JAVA_OPTIONS' in section 'Service'

Tags: java, linux, clojure, systemd

I'm running a website in Clojure. Here http://www.luminusweb.net/docs/deployment.md it says:

> Note that by default JVM is fairly aggressive about memory usage. If
> you're like to reduce the amount of memory used then you can add the
> following line under the [Service] configuration:
>
> [Service] ...
>
> _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx256m" ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /var/myapp/myapp.jar

However, after adding it to my service file, I get an exception:

```
Unknown lvalue '_JAVA_OPTIONS' in section 'Service'
```

Comment: It's really strange cause it works well in a bash-script. I've just run against the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid [systemd.service(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) syntax. You can specify environment variables using another directive:

```
Environment=_JAVA_OPTIONS='-Xmx256m'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /var/myapp/myapp.jar
```